# hasOne() not returning relationships because of method name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I am using laravel 5.3, I have listings table with hasOne relationship to cities table.

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\City', 'id', 'city_id');
}
```

on my view

```
{{$listing->city->name}}
```

this cause error

> Trying to get property of non-object

But when I change the method name to other than city,

```
public function foo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\City', 'id', 'city_id');
}
```

on my view

```
{{$listing->foo->name}}
```

This one works.

What cause the problem with city method name? 
I have never problem with city method name in other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you use **city** as object's attribute somewhere else in your code - it already contains the value so this value is used instead of the relation.

Look for some places where you set the value of **$listing->city**, try doing **dd($listing->city)** for a clue. And if you can't find it, post some more of your code, as the error lies somewhere else than what you posted so far.